# QGraphicsView show items from edges

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene, qgraphicsitem

I am not able to draw from the edges using `QGraphicsView`

I am using following code

```
#include <QApplication>

#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QGraphicsView>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  QApplication a(argc, argv);
  QMainWindow win;

  QGraphicsScene scene;
  scene.addRect(0, 0, 1000, 20, {}, Qt::red);

  QGraphicsView view;
  view.setScene(&scene);

  win.setCentralWidget(&view);

  win.show();

  return a.exec();
}
```

above draws rectangle in the center but i want rectangle and all other QGraphicsItems to draw from `win` 's edges, following regular window's gui coordinate system

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I know what you mean but... you could try setting the [alignment property](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsview.html#alignment-prop) of the `QGraphicsView`.

Comment: thanks... that worked